# Problems loading xdebug in wampserver2.0

Tags: apache2, wamp, xdebug, wampserver

I have an issue loading xdebug in apache server.

Here are my settings:

Apache 2.2.11
MySQL  5.1.36
PHP    5.2.0
Windows 7
Wampserver 2.0

php -i and php -m show that the xdebug module php_xdebug-2.1.0RC1-5.2-vc6.dll is installed.

However phpinfo() does not show that xdebug is installed. I have tried starting apache as a service, through the Wampserver UI, and by running httpd directly (as administrator) and I have checked permissions on the php_xdebug-2.1.0RC1-5.2-vc6.dll file.

There are no warnings in the logs. In the apache error log I get:

[Thu Jun 24 11:20:55 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) PHP/5.2.0 configured -- resuming normal operations

Has anyone any ideas?

Thank you,

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue as I was using wampserver2.0 and naively assumed I could use c:\wamp\bin\php\php{version#}\php.ini to affect my configuration.

In actual fact one must use c:\wamp\apache\Apache{version#}\bin\php.ini to configure php on the wamp server.

Hope this helps anyone else who might one day tear their hair out over this.

John

Answer (score 1):

I already do like you said but nothing happens
Using WAMPSERVER 2.1 , php_xdebug-2.1.0-5.3-vc6.dll (however I renamed it becoming php_xdebug.dll)

In php.ini, I also modified as instructions

```
extension=php_xdebug.dll
...

zend_extension = "C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.3/ext/php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

After starting the server again, there are no error in Apache log, everything seems work normal.Still do not see any information about xdebug from phpinfo. I totally **gave up** :(
Any ideas for my case, appreciated that.

Comment: I'm not sure how your server is set-up but I know there are probabaly several php.ini's hanging around. Did you try all of them?